# Rebuilding website from Django 0.96 to Django 1.2

Tags: python, django, web

I've got a website done in **Django 0.96** (done in 2007), and now we are thinking about rebuilding it (not just migrating) for **Django 1.2** .

Can anyone point me to the new (and worth the while) widgets, plugins and other stuff for **Django 1.2** (released in april 2010).

I've heard of "South" and of a widget for debugging (can't remember the name), but I'm a little lost here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Django API is amazingly stable so you may not have to rewrite it at all (unless you really want to).

I have a site I did in 2007 using 0.97-pre -- at least I think that's what they called it, it was trunk 6688. Anyway, I have ported the site twice, once to 1.0 and then to 1.1.1. The only "major" thing we had to deal with was Admin moving into its own file, but that was mostly cut-and-paste in the editor plus a few tweaks. You'll run into small stuff like `maxlength` going to `max_length`, etc., but that's easy stuff to deal with.

Check the lists of [Backward Incompatible Changes](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/BackwardsIncompatibleChanges), and [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.1/#backwards-incompatible-changes-in-1-1), and [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.2-alpha-1/#backwards-incompatible-changes-in-1-2) to see if anything jumps out at you. Read through the [ORM docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/#the-model-layer) as if you've never seen them before -- a *lot* has changed. You may want to look at some of your model relationships and queries and see if the revised ORM makes some of them easier/more efficient to do.

I recommend using [Grappelli](http://code.google.com/p/django-grappelli/) along with [Filebrowser](http://code.google.com/p/django-filebrowser/) (in fact I think the recent releases of filebrowser *require* grappelli). Take a look at [Pinax](http://pinaxproject.com/) for a whole bushel basket of apps brought together under one roof. There's a lot out there and you sort of have to poke around a little. Depending on what you're doing, [GeoDjango](http://geodjango.org/) may be of interest to you. Etc., etc. I'm sure you'll have fun with all of the new toys.

Answer (score 2):

You probably heard about the [django-debug-toolbar](http://github.com/robhudson/django-debug-toolbar)

Comment: Yeahh that's the one. Don't you know any more new stuff I'm missing out on?

Answer (score 0):

Of course, there's the [release notes](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/), but the rest is just stuff you... find.

[South](http://south.aeracode.org/) is for schema migration, not debugging.